# Unique tables for specific customers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently designing a billing app that can be used for a consultant to bill their customers. I currently have 3 tables in mysql for this the database to store information. The tables are activity, customer and expenses.

In the activity table I've got activity_id, activity_name, percent_rate, hours

In the customer table I've got customer_id, and all the information on the customer

In the expense table I've got expense_id, description, cost, quantity

I'm trying to figure out how to design the database that I can keep track of the hours spent on activity per customer. I want it to be used for multiple customers, but can't figure out how to structure the database for this.

Is it best to use a foreign key like custId in the activity table?

Comment: Get use to hearing that depends.... On the surface adding customer_ID to activity as a foreign key makes sense, but would activities be "re-used" for different customers?  Could an activity be split between customers? If so then you need an associative table.  If an activity is always for one customer and a Customer can have zero or many activities, then customer_Id in Activity makes sense.  Ask yourself in terms of carnality and design is easier to figure out.

Comment: Yea... does an activity get reused for multiple customers? Could an activity being used against two different customers incur different expense_id's? These are good questions to determine the right way to go. My guess is a 4th table that holds the relationship (probably with a date or date range) between the Customer, Activity, and Expense.

Comment: All activities will be used for all customers. Same with the expenses as well. Using a 4th table makes sense because I'll need to date stamp all the activities.

I'll also have several of the same activities with different date stamps as well to grab a date range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

But a lot depends on your overall structure. That's a pretty simple data model. If for instance you had something like "project", that the activities are related to, you'd put the customer id in the project table. Then again, if there were multiple customers for that activity, you'd have another table, with activity_id and customer_id in it, just to show that relationship. So, it depends on the problems you're trying to model.

Comment: Basically I'll have a project that I'll be performing many of the activities on. I'll have to keep track off each hour spent on each activity of the project.

Maybe I'll have a project table with the information on it like activity id, customer id, etc...

Comment: It would more be the other way around. If the project table is the overarching "Work", then it's identifier would be the project id, and the activity table would contain that project id, as you would have one project with many activities.

Comment: http://imgur.com/yLajcnu

This is how my database is laid out. Ultimately I want to produce an invoice for the customer based on all the activities

Comment: Those are basic tables, but there is no link between the tables. How is customer linked to activity and invoice? How is invoice linked to activity? How is expense linked to anything? You'll need flags and dates to indicates which activities have been billed for, and which ones have been paid. Do you have standard activities, with standard rates? Do you want to track what rates are given to individual customers, if that's different? Just a few things that come to mind.

Comment: I haven't quite linked them yet. Those are some of the problems I am running into. I'm pretty new to setting up database, I'm do more of java coding than anything.

Basically the invoice will be linked to the customer, and on the invoice you'll have each activity done for the customer and the hours spent on the activity. The expenses is linked to the invoice as well as any expenses that were done during the project.

As far as rate goes, basically there is a per hour rate but each activity is a percentage of that rate

Comment: I need a way to get multiple activities each having their own hours spent on to the invoice and unique to a certain customer.

Comment: So, the way it works, is that if you have a many to many relationship, for instance if each activity could have many customers, and customers could have many activities, you would create another table that has just the customer id and the activity id in it to link those things. In the case where you have each activity can only be on one invoice, you would include the invoice id on each activity record. That's called a foreign key. You can define it as a foreign key in the database, or just deal with in your code, but that field has to be present on the record in the database.

Comment: Don't know if you are building this through some kind of java database ORM, or building the tables by hand - I'm an old database guy, so I normally do the latter.

Comment: So let's say I've got a table named Project where I've got the customer id and activity id. Would I add the hours for the activity on the activity table or the project table? How would I store the hours individually for each activity based on the customer? And can I make it where I have multiple instances of the same activity based off a date stamp?

I'm doing this part in MySQL. Eventually I'll move to java to talk to the database.

Comment: You would only have the activity id in the project record, if you had only one activity per project. If you had multiple activities per project, you would have one row for each activity in the activity table, and the project id would be on that record. You would have the hours for each activity on that activity record, also, but only if you are totalling up all the hours for that activity in one spot. But if you want to track that you had 3 hours on that activity today, two hours the next day, 12 the day after that, then that would be another table.

Comment: That table would have the activity id, and individual hours.  Any time you think, "I can have more than one of these associated with this record," you are looking at another table. That activity table would probably have a key of three fields, from the sounds of it - project id, activity id, and date of that work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This cleared everything up for me. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it. Does each activity have one (and only one) customer? Then you could have activity_id be the primary key of the `activity` table, and customer_id be a foreign key. For each customer you can get a list of activities, and for each activity you can figure out the # of hours the consultant worked for that customer on that activity.